# How to make function that some parameters not required in when call it in iOS Swift 3?

Tags: swift, function, option-type

I wanna make function without some required parameters like this:

```
func myMethod(Name name:String,Age age:Int){
    print(name)
}

//call
myMethod(Name:"Donald")
```

Is this can be?

Comment: Note that it's convention for argument labels to be `lowerCamelCase`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just have to make them nilable.

```
func myMethod(name name: String? = nil, age age: Int? = nil) {
    print(name!)
}
```

**Notice**: when yo make parameters optional, you have to be careful about how to unwrap them. usually using `if let` syntax is helpful.

```
func myMethod(name name: String? = nil, age age: Int? = nil) {
  if let name = name {
     print(name)
  }
}
```

you can also provide default value for them:

```
func myMethod(name name: String? = "Donald", age age: Int? = 10) {
    print(name!)
}
```

Comment: If you're providing non-optional default values for the parameters, there's no need to make the parameter types optional.